# Scaffold generated Sum of all Integers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

This is driving me nuts with loads of undeclared variables. I have created a simple scaffold with text and integers. How to sum up all integers? See image:

[image]

I only want to sum up the "Watts". Im using Rails 4; Ruby 2.1.3

I get this: `undefined method 'all' for nil:NilClass`" when I put this code in my `app/models/bathroom_accessory.rb`:

```
def total
 @bathroom_accessory.all.sum(&:watts)
end
```

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: `all` is a class-level method so you can't call it from an instance.

Comment: That's not true.  You can absolutely call it.  The trouble is what he's calling it on, not where he's calling it from. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this (without the all):

```
 def total
   BathroomAccessory.sum(:watts)
 end
```

For the sake of the question, is important for the OP to understand this call:

```
@bathroom_accessory.all.sum(&:watts)
```

Is incorrect since sum is defined at a class level and @bathroom_accessory is declared as an instance variable.  Even this code is incorrect:

```
 def total
   @bathroom_accessory = BathroomAccessory.new
   @bathroom_accessory.sum(:watts)
 end
```

This last code will raise a NoMethodError error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your answer works. Took me time to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to refer to an instance variable rather than the collection of all accessories:

```
def total
  BathroomAccessory.all.sum(&:watts)
end
```